# Site Guest User can not send email in force.com site in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have already searched it through what could be the possible reason for not being able to send a single email as a site guest user on force.com site in salesforce

- Site guest user's email should be valid
- Site guest user has all the permission for sending email in public access
- Site guest user has all the required permission for the vf page along with the apex class

furthermore, I checked all the debug logs for the event and I couldn't find anything unusual

this is my demo code which is perfectly working fine for the admin user

```
List<String> to = new List<String>();
// to.add(quoterec.OwnerId);
to.add('myEmail@gmail.com');
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setSubject('Quote Accepted by Customer');
email.setToAddresses(to);
email.setHtmlBody('Quote Accepted by Customer');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
System.debug('Test: Check Debug log ==> ' + email);
```